# Opportunity Detail Export

Tags: data-export

Does anyone know of a simple way to export details from an opportunity record into a styled form?  Our sales team export all the details to Docusign to create a client contract.  We're trying to export the data into a styled Excel form to create a handover document containing all the detail to our operations team.  We can export it straight to CSV, but it's not pretty.  Looked at Documotion or Conga Composer but they are expensive for what we need.

Many thanks,

Comment: take a look at Conga Composer  - they specialize in this type of application

Answer (score 0):

You could create a report. This might be a good option for you if the users are going to be responsible for exporting the data. Your users could then run this report and [export the results to Excel](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_export.htm&type=5). The format of the export could be native Excel (XLSX), thus allowing you to retain any report formatting you built in Salesforce. No work in Excel at all.